# Why does Requests' Session.get() raise an requests.exceptions.ConnectionError instead of requests.exceptions.Timeout, when a timeout occurs?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, python-requests

I'm sending a Requests GET request using a `Session` as follows:

```
with requests.Session() as rs:
    with rs.get(url, params={}, headers={}, auth=self.auth, verify=self.ssl_verify, timeout=30) as r:
        ...
```

I was expecting a `requests.exceptions.Timeout` error to be raised, when the `timeout=30` had elapsed, but instead a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/confluence/confluence.py", line 118, in __producer
    with rs.get(url, params={}, headers={}, auth=self.auth, verify=self.ssl_verify, timeout=30) as r:
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 683, in send
    r.content
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 829, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/Users/nlykkei/projects/atlassian-watchdog/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 758, in generate
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='confluence.danskenet.net', port=443): Read timed out.
```

The [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) clearly states that:

> If a request times out, a Timeout exception is raised.

So, why is a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` raised in my case?

Comment: From docs: In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused connection, etc), Requests will raise a ConnectionError exception.

Comment: So, the request is not timing out. The error is related to some other network issue. The timeout you are referring to is that time client will wait for response *after* a connection has been established.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the connection state, the `timeout` parameter affects timeouts after the connection has been established according to the documentation you've linked (i.e. time between bytes on an established connection). For your case it seems like the connection is never established, and thus, a connection error is raised instead.

Comment: @narendra-choudhary - In my case, the exception is thrown, when the client looses internet connection briefly. Have you any idea what the `Read timed out` is referring to then?

Comment: @narendra-choudhary - Also, the exception is also raised, if I use `timeout=`.

Comment: @MatsLindh - what’s weird is that the error is only raised, if I use the timeout parameter. Without it, the app just hangs indefinitely. Any ideas?